# Multiple git repositories in the same directory

Tags: git, bitbucket

I would like to have files from multiple git repositories cloned in the same directory.

Due to size restrictions (from Bitbucket) I had to split up a large project into several smaller repositories. Each repository contains a few folders, and when put together they all make up for a large project:

- Repo 1:

  - Dir1
  - Dir2
- Repo 2:

  - Dir3

Final structure:

- Dir1
- Dir2
- Dir3

The idea is fairly simple and would very easily be done by using branches, but as I mentioned due to the project's size that's not possible.

Would it be possible to do this, possibly with `.gitignore`. Any other ideas are welcome.

Comment: Submodules might be useful here, but the bigger question is why was your project so large that it needed to be broken up?  I have never heard of this, and I am worried that maybe you have tons of binaries in there causing the repo size to explode.

Comment: Yeah, the project does have a large amount of needed binaries including maps and their size exceeds Bitbucket's ~1.5GB limit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use symlinks to the directories.

```
project/
- dir1 -> link to repo1/dir1
- dir2 -> link to repo1/dir2
- dir3 -> link to repo2/dir3
- repo1 -> git repository
--- dir1
--- dir2
- repo2 -> git repository
--- dir3
```

That requires you, however, to commit changes to both repos manually.
Switching branches must also be made for both projects simultaneously.
Of course you can automate that, I think.
However, managing two repositories will never be as easy as a single one.

However, if you have such a large repository, really re-think what you actually want to have under version control. Binaries, and any other form of automatically-generated files (e.g. PDF from LaTeX, PNG from SVG, archive `sources.zip` of all sources), usually do not belong under version control. The same is true for recorded data that should never change (e.g. photographs, videos, log files).

Comment: Would symlinks work on windows?  

I don't mind managing the repos separately since I've groupped the dirs in a somewhat organized way.

Unfortunately there's a bunch of binaries including large "map" files which cannot be generated. I've cut down as much as possible from that project and it still exceeds the required size by Bitbucket.  Unfortunately compilation needs to happen on the development machine because the compilers can't be installed on the server (destination machine).

Comment: "Would symlinks work on windows?" Please first google, that distracts from the actual question. (If there is really no answer - and I am sure there is - then you may ask a new question on the appropriate site). — So these large map files are actually generated? Then you should copy them using another protocol (for instance FTP, HTTP (e.g. using Dropbox/Google Drive or other services)) to the server.

Comment: It's actually very relevant, because your solution might only work on *NIX operating systems which should be mentioned. The map files aren't generated, however they are often manually edited so having them under version control does somewhat help. I don't think any diff tool can actually show the changes made in the file as it is recognized as a binary file.